# Font-awesome works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, font-awesome

I have added font-awesome to my project and it works locally in the newest Rails, but while I try to deploy to Heroku the app is crashing (after git push heroku master), I can't understand why and find any solution.

```
remote:         [0] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 905 bytes {0} [built]
remote:         [2] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
remote:         [4] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 900 bytes {0} [built]
remote:         [8] ./app/javascript/channels/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
remote:         [9] ./app/javascript/channels sync _channel\.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [12] ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 2.76 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
remote:            + 12 hidden modules
remote:        
remote:        ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
remote:        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot' in '/tmp/build_0f15e44a/app/javascript/stylesheets'
```

**File application.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'
require("stylesheets/application.scss")
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
```

**and this to application.scss**

```
$fa-font-path: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims';
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6#heroku-gems

Comment: Make sure webpack has all dependencies `rake yarn:install `